# IntegrationTests - A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, integration-testing, web-config, asp.net-4.0

I get this error: `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?).` when this URI: `http://www.site.com/%3f`.

How can I write an integration tests around of all of this type of errors?
  I want to test against all this erros:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client
A potentially dangerous Request.Cookies value was detected from the client
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? How your application reacts to certain broken URLs?