# ASP.NET 4 URL limitations: why URL cannot contain any %3f characters

Tags: url, asp.net-4.0

```
http://site.com/page%3fcharacter
```

This URL will return the following error:

```
Illegal characters in path.
```

I'm already put this in web.config:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
<pages validateRequest="false"> 
...
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to allow the request through, you need to add `requestPathInvalidCharacters` and set it to an empty string:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
</system.web>
```

**Edit** You should leave your original question in place, because now my answer does not make sense.

But in answer to your second question, that it's because %3f corresponds to '?' which is not allowed in file names on Windows. You can set the `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` property to `true` to change this behaviour:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters=""
                 relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
</system.web>
```

You might want to look through all of the properties in the [HttpRuntimeSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection_properties%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class to see if there's any others that might apply.

You can also implement a sub class of [RequestValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.requestvalidator.aspx) and set up your web.config to use your subclass (that will presumably allow all URLs through?). Personally, I wouldn't bother and just let the built-in classes handle it. It's unlikely that a normal user is every going to *accidentally* type in "%3f" in a path, and why bother going to so much trouble to improve the use-case for malicious users?

This, by the way, is actually a new feature in ASP.NET 4, which is why Stack Overflow doesn't spit out an error: it's running on .NET 3.5.

Comment: That solved the problem. but I get another error for another url. I will edit the question.

Comment: 1. Rewrite the path. 2. return a blank page (or custom error page). 3. redirect to home page. I want to have the power to decide how to respond to this kind of error.

Comment: Can I have integration tests for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831075/integrationtests-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-t

Comment: hi,I have used "relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"",but this could not run in live,only working in mylocal

Answer (score 14):

Here's a nice article by Hanselman explaining all the nooks and crannies related to your issue:

[Experiments in Wackiness: Allowing percents, angle-brackets, and other naughty things in the ASP.NET/IIS Request URL](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Probably because that looks a lot like a malformed url.

& is used as a separator for the query string parameters i.e. site.com/page?some=20&another=15

Comment: That's right. but imagine that someone post a url like this to your site and the user see an error like this... this confusing!