# ASP.NET special characters in URL (colon) not working even with requestPathInvalidCharacters=""

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, special-characters, asp.net-4.0

I need to pass a colon within an URL in ASP.NET, like "http://mywebapp.com/Portal:Main/". Wikipedia does this a lot, and colons are valid URL characters according to the RFC.

I've found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831142/asp-net-4-url-limitations-why-url-cannot-contain-any-3f-characters) and read through [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) which covers the invalid characters filter in ASP.NET.

Using VS2010 Ultimate and trying with a new ASP.NET WebForms and a new ASP.NET MVC 2 project I always added this to my web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
```

as well as this

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"
    requestPathInvalidCharacters=""
    relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"
/>
```

But still, I always get a Error 400: Bad Gateway when accessing anything with a "special character" like `http://localhost:2021/1%3As.aspx` or `http://localhost:2021/1:s.aspx`

The projects are definitely using .NET 4 runtime. Whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer the question myself as I found out in the meantime:

You have to flip a registry switch for it to work:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET

DWord Value Name: VerificationCompatibility 
Value Data: 1
```

See the [according MS KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932552) for more details.

For mono users: the registry value is honored on windows systems. On non-windows systems you can change the behaviour by adding a monoSettings section to your web.config:

```
<monoSettings verificationCompatibility="1" />
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"
    requestPathInvalidCharacters=""
    relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"
/>
```